# Vue computed property in router template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, computed-properties

I'm having trouble understanding how to get a computed property all the way out through the router to my template. Here's a basic idea of what I'm doing:

```
const Home = {
  template: '<router-link to="/level/1">Level 1</router-link>'
}

const Level = {
  template: '<template>|{{ id }}|{{ message }}|</template>',
  props: ['id','message']
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home, props: true },
    { path: '/level/:id', component: Level, props: true }
  ]
})

const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<router-view></router-view>',
    computed: {
        message() {
            return 'HELLO';
    }
  }
})
```

When I click the "Level 1" link, the result I expect to see is:

> |1|HELLO|

The result I actually see is:

> |1||

The final usage will be a bit more functional than this, but hopefully that's enough to expose whatever it is that I'm not understanding about props, or routing, or computed properties.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1) There's an error:

> Cannot use `<template>` as component root element because it may contain multiple nodes.

So change that to a `div`.  When using the Vue CLI, templates are wrapped in `<template>` but there still needs to be a different root element inside of it.

2) The `Level` component has a prop called `message` but it isn't passed.  The `Home` route passes `id` but not `message`.  `Home` can't pass `message` at the moment, because it's in the root component, and `Home` didn't receive it.

You could:

- Use Vuex to solve this most cleanly
- Define `message` in `Home` instead of the root and pass it to `Level`
- Pass the `message` from root to `Home` and then again from `Home` to `Level`

Comment: On #1 - although I don't doubt that you are correct that I need a `<div>` instead of `<template>`, I'm doubtful that this is causing `message` not to show up, since `id` is showing.  
  
On #2 - I know that the variables aren't getting passed properly. I just don't know how to correct the problem. Probably I'm misunderstanding props - the documentation makes it seem like props is the magic word to get variables to go places. Obviously that's not the case!

Comment: Do you see how the `Level` path has a [dynamic segment](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) for `/:id`?  This is what lets you pass a route param for `id`.  The param is passed via the url in that spot.  Since the `Level` route has no `/:message` segment in the route definition, and no attempt to pass anything in that url slot, the param isn't passed.  The `props: true` setting additionally registers those params as props, as though they had been passed from a parent component as props.

Comment: If that's the only way to get a variable through to the template, then I'm going to have a real problem, because "Hello" is just an example. I don't really want my variables present in the URL. I guess I'll be looking into Vuex then.

Comment: Actually you can pass whole objects through params without even declaring segments for them.  (This is done through the `router-link`'s `params` property, and doesn't go in the url.)  So technically the issue here is really only that there's no attempt to pass a `message` param.  I'm not sure if it's encouraged to pass an object that way, it may be an anti-pattern.  Vuex makes everything trivial:  set some variable from anywhere, then check it from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Dan! I managed to solve my original, more complicated problem by just directly referencing the global object that I had already created, completely doing an end run around props. I'm sure the style purists are throwing up a little in their mouths to read that! On the example I posted above, I tried to work with params in my router-link, but ironically I never did get my "simplified" code fixed. If anyone wants to write a code example that solves my broken code above, it would be a cool thing to have for future Googlers, but I've worked through my immediate problem.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you figured it out.  A global object is essentially what Vuex does as well (with several advantages).