# Need help using Vue methods in routed templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm sure this information is out there somewhere, but I've been Googling all afternoon and haven't been able phrase my question in a way that gets me the understanding I need. I want to write a method in my Vue instance and use it in a template that I display using routing. Here's some partial code:

```
const Home = { template: 
  '<div class="container">' +
    'I\'m leaving some stuff out, but routing works fine in the real code' +
  '</div>'
};

const Level = { template: 
  '<div class="container">' +
    '<h2>Level {{ id }}</h2>' +
    '{{ say_hello }}' +
  '</div>',
    props: ['id','say_hello']
}

// === Define our routes ===
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home, props: true },
        { path: '/level/:id', component: Level, props: true }
    ]
})

// === Now fire up Vue and display it on screen ===
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<router-view></router-view><p><router-link to="/level/1">Level 1</router-link></p>',
    methods: {
        say_hello: function() {     
            return 'hello';
        }
    }
})
```

I realize that's a little bit of a mess, but in the full code it all works EXCEPT that my '{{ say_hello }}' never works, no matter what I try. I basically always get some variety of "is undefined" or "is not a function" error message. My guess is that the method is not making it past the router for whatever reason, but I haven't been able to figure out what to fix to make it work.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I just realized that this is basically a variation of a question I asked a couple of weeks ago, which I never really got an answer to that helped me figure out the problem (several answers, but none that clicked for me). I wound up sidestepping the issue using globals last time. I'd really like to figure out how this actually works instead! Previous question: [Vue computed property in router template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314809/vue-computed-property-in-router-template)

Comment: You've set `say_hello` as a prop in your `Level` component but you're never passing anything in to it. Do you want to pass the return value from your `say_hello` method or do were you wanting your `Level` component to execute the `say_hello` method somehow?

Comment: In the Level component, I want to replace ```{{ say_hello }}``` with the word "hello".

Answer (score 0):

You can get vue-router to pass any params offered into component props using `props: true`.

This way, you can construct your `<router-link>` elements with any extra data you want. All you have to do is pass in `params`. This is best facilitated by using a named route, eg

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Level', params: { id: 1, say_hello: 'whatever' } }">
```

For example

```js
const Home = { template: 
  `<div class="container">
    I'm leaving some stuff out, but routing works fine in the real code
  </div>`
};

const Level = { template:
  `<div class="container">
    <h2>Level {{ id }}</h2>
    {{ say_hello }}
  </div>`,
  props: {
    id: [String, Number],
    say_hello: {
      default: 'Nobody said hello '
    }
  }
}

// === Define our routes ===
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home, props: true },
        { path: '/level/:id', name: 'Level', component: Level, props: true }
    ]
})

// === Now fire up Vue and display it on screen ===
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: () => ({
    say_hello: 'hello'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<router-view></router-view>
<p>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'Level', params: { id: 1, say_hello } }">Level 1</router-link>
</p>
<pre>$route.fullPath = {{ $route.fullPath }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to pass data - I'm trying to allow access to a method.

Comment: @TulsaMJ that's what I was asking you in the comments above. Could you please edit your question to clarify? Personally, I would not recommend passing functions between components.